# Unable to run `rails g` or `rails c` without `sudo`

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, sudo, gemfile

I am unable to run `rails g` or `rails c`, because of the following error message:

```
Could not find mysql2-0.3.18 in any of the sources
Run `bundle install` to install missing gems.
```

I can run 'rails server', which works fine, as expected. I also have ran `bundle install`, with no errors (this line is in my `Gemfile`: `gem 'mysql2'`). The database works fine with `rails server`, but seems to break with `rails g`/`c`.

#### Update:

I can run `rails g` and `rails c` with `sudo`. I think it's a problem with my path - I think I might have installed MySQL as root.

Comment: bundler can't find this gem so you're probably having a PATH issue

Comment: @Anthony how do I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried running those commands using Bundler?

```
bundle exec rails c

bundle exec rails g
```